# How do I switch between Navigation Controllers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

**Situation:**
I have an Xcode project based on the "Navigation-Based-Application" template. So that means I have a SINGLE UINavigationController that manages a UIViewController.

**What I want To Do:**
What I want to do is add one more UINavigationController to my project -- and be able to switch back and forth between them. *(I want to do this to make space for some seperate unrelated content so that it does not have a back button pointing back to the root view controller.)*

**Question:**
How do I add one more UINavigationController to my project and switch between the two UINavigationControllers?

Comment: Why not just hide the back button?

Comment: How are you changing between the two areas? A UITabBarController?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most common, and natural iPhone OS, way of doing this is to add a `UITabBarController` to your application. The Xcode template *Tab Bar Application* will guide you in the right direction on how to use it.

But...

If you don't like to have a Tab Bar in your application, and wish to switch between different `UINavigationController` instances (or any `UIViewController` for that matter), you can do something like this.

First you need to create your `UINavigationController` instances in a appropriate place (for example a new view controller, or in you Application Delegate, if you want to take the easy way out). You can then switch between controllers by just swapping which Navigation Controller's view that should be visible.

Example in the Application Delegate, "firstNavigationController" and "secondNavigationController" are `UINavigationController` instance variables:

```
- (void)showFirstNavigationController {
    [secondNavigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:firstNavigationController.view];
}
```

This will simply display the first instead of the second Navigation Controller. Note that this example is very simple. I didn't take into consideration that you should correctly handle the methods `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:` and so on.

Comment: Thanks -- and for extra credit: How can I make the transition smooth (or animated)?

Comment: You can accomplish that easy with some basic `UIView` animations. Before the first row in my method, add: `[UIView beginAnimations:@"myFlip" context:NULL];` and `[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];` And in the bottom: `[UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: how to do this in swift?

Comment: The same methods can be called with swift. However, this answer is over 6 years old, and there are better ways to do this these days. Take a look at View Controller Containment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html